# Use TFT LCD with Uno and Wi-Fi shield

Tags: lcd, wifi

I need to work with Arduino Uno, LCD and Wi-Fi shield.

I was wondering whether I can use the LCD in the link, [2.2" TFT Display - Test the Display](https://learn.adafruit.com/2-2-tft-display/test-the-display) with the Uno and Wi-Fi shield - and how to search for them?

Comment: You may even ask adafruit support (they are pretty good at support). But, because of the possibility of having multiple shields use the same pins, I don't use shields.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking which pins are used by the shields and if there is any conflicts. Check the shield schematics and example libraries.

If there are any conflicts, check if the shields has any jumpers that may be used to change the pin configuration.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the arduino Uno will work with that LCD display and can work with wifi shield at same time too.

Answer (score 0):

Providing they're I2C shields, it is possible to use both at the same time, you may have to write your own modifications to allow this however as each shields library may assume it is the sole connected shield.